# SharePoint 2010 People Picker Limitations issue

Tags: infopath, people-picker

I have a SharePoint 2010 Infopath List form. In this form I have a people picker field and a Date picker field. Now I need to make people picker field Mandatory only when Date picker field is not blank. How can I do this as Action, validation are not available for People Picker and we cannot use custom code for an Infopath List form ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution :

By creating another field (name it PersonValidator or something) and setting its default value to the AccountId field of the Contact Selector, then add a section control below/above/beside the Contact Selector that is hidden, UNLESS the PersonValidator field is populated when the Date field is populated.

This section control should have red/bold/italicized text in it stating that the Contact Selector may not be blank. Also, make the PersonValidator field conditionally required by using a Validation rule that says, "If DateField is not blank and PersonValidator IS blank."

This is an indirect method for making a Contact Selector conditionally required.